# writing SOAP API for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, soap

i am building an android app whereby i want it requests and response using the SOAP API. 
I am currently using an example i got but the example doesn't work, i already asked the host but he is not replying.
So here is the code;

```
Button bt;
String TAG = "Response";
SoapPrimitive resultString;
EditText celsius;
String getCel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    celsius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);

    //add button listener
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            getCel = celsius.getText().toString();
            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            task.execute();

        }
    });
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        Calculate();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response" + resultString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void Calculate() {
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
    String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

    try {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("Celsius", getCel);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

i am getting an error which says: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Plz chk this url: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx it is not working

Comment: Please provide which demo you have Use?

Comment: so the website doesn't work. is everything else ok??

Comment: i lost the website name where i got the demo.

Comment: ok @Riley B. I am sending you one Url . try this

Comment: try my answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Your URLS are wrong, they´ve changed.
Try this ones:

```
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
    String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";
```

I hope it works for you. let me know

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
public class TabelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetIDSSupportData";

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetIDSSupportData";
//change url here
private static String URL = "http://166.62.119.183:8066/IDSSupportData.asmx";
String pksupportid,userid,username,email,subject,desc,entrydate,modatetime,issolved,imgsrc;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

  bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
   //add button listener
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("Pageno","1");

    request.addProperty("PageSize","20");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.dotNet = true;


    try {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;





        if (result != null) {
            //Get the first property and change the label text
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
        /*   JSONObject  jsonObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            Log.i("jobj",jsonObj.toString());*/
         /*   Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(result.toString());*/
            //Log.i("json",json);
            TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();

            SoapObject root = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
            // Log.i("root", root.toString());
            SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("NewDataSet");

            //  Log.i("sd0", s_deals.toString());

            int flag = 1;

            for(int i= -1;i<s_deals.getPropertyCount();i++){

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(TabelActivity.this);

                tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(

                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                if (flag == 1) {


                        TextView b6 = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);

                        b6.setText("Id");

                        b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                        b6.setTextSize(15);

                        tr.addView(b6);

                        TextView b19 = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);

                        b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

                        b19.setTextSize(15);

                        b19.setText("Name");

                        b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                        tr.addView(b19);

                        TextView b29 = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);

                        b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

                        b29.setText("Status");

                        b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                        b29.setTextSize(15);

                        tr.addView(b29);

                        tv.addView(tr);

                        final View vline = new View(TabelActivity.this);

                        vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));

                        vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                        tv.addView(vline);

                        flag = 0;

                    }
                else {

                    SoapObject s_deals_1 = (SoapObject) s_deals.getProperty(i);

                    pksupportid = s_deals_1.getProperty("PkSupportId").toString();
                    userid = s_deals_1.getProperty("UserId").toString();
                    username = s_deals_1.getProperty("UserName").toString();
                    email = s_deals_1.getProperty("EmailId").toString();
                    subject = s_deals_1.getProperty("Subject").toString();
                    desc = s_deals_1.getProperty("Description").toString();
                    issolved = s_deals_1.getProperty("IsSolved").toString();
                    entrydate = s_deals_1.getProperty("EntryDate").toString();
                    imgsrc = "http://media.westsidechevrolet.com/houston/624064%20wtf.jpg";
                    TextView b = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);

                    String stime = pksupportid;

                    b.setText(stime);

                    b.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                    b.setTextSize(15);

                    tr.addView(b);


                    TextView b1 = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);

                    b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

                    b1.setTextSize(15);

                    String stime1 =  username;

                    b1.setText(stime1);

                    b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    tr.addView(b1);

                    TextView b2 = new TextView(TabelActivity.this);
                    b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

                    String stime2 = desc;

                    b2.setText(stime2);

                    b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    b2.setTextSize(15);

                    tr.addView(b2);

                    tv.addView(tr);




                    final View vline1 = new View(TabelActivity.this);

                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));

                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                    tv.addView(vline1);


                }


            }





        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
   }
   });
   }
```

in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

add jar file in your lib folder
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

in your app level gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
```

Please Change in your code and check it:

```
public void Calculate() {
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";

try {
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("Celsius", getCel);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new    

    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

    Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: your solution work but as you can see, i am trying to link a button so that when clicked it can do the SOAP Api

Comment: can you please edit out where you add a textView and table row the code is confusing. i just have one BUTTON, one TEXTVIEW and EDIT TEXT. i just need to know where i actually went wrong in the code i have. what i have currently doesn't have any errors, it just crashes. i don't where this crash is happening. help if you can. Your code works fine.